# Mongoose won't connect. - But no error in the console

Tags: database, mongodb, express, mongoose, backend

I'm trying to connect my app.js to MongoDB.
Worked the last time. This time, in this new project, it won't connect. And I don't get a console log. Neither get I an error-log.
Is there something wrong in the code? or is ist a MongoDB problem. I tripple-checked the username and password.

## .env-File:

```
PORT = 8080
MONGO_DB_CLIENT = "mongodb+srv://Admin:<mypassword>@g5-cluster0.vthttto.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority"
```

## app.js

```
require('dotenv').config();
console.log(process.env.MONGO_DB_CLIENT);

const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT;
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const cors = require('cors');

app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());

const connectString = process.env.MONGO_DB_CLIENT;
app.use(async(req,res,next) => {
   try {
       await mongoose.connect(connectString,{
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true,
    })
    console.log("Connected to MongoDB");
    next();

    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
});
```

## package.json  dependencies

```
  "dependencies": {
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^16.3.1",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "mongoose": "^7.6.3"
  },
```

- I tripple-checked the username and password.
- Installed mongo db as well, didn't help. So i deleted it again. (i have mongoose)
- i logged:

```
console.log(process.env.MONGO_DB_CLIENT);
```

...this works.

**update - i tried:**

```
async function connectToMongoDB() {
  try {
    console.log(process.env.MONGO_DB_CLIENT);
    await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_DB_CLIENT, {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
    });
    console.log('Connected to the DB ✅');
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}

connectToMongoDB();
```

**this is what the console said:**

```
[1] MongoServerError: bad auth : authentication failed 
[1]     at MessageStream.<anonymous>
[1]   ok: 0,
[1]   code: 8000,
[1]   codeName: 'AtlasError',
[1]   connectionGeneration: 0,
[1]   [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(2) { 'HandshakeError', 'ResetPool' }
```

...so it must be a mongoDB authenication problem then i guess.. :/

Comment: What is the indication that it is not connecting?

Comment: the indication was, that didn't got any console.log at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
try {
  console.log(process.env.MONGO_DB_CLIENT)
  await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_DB_CLIENT);
  console.log( 'Connected to the DB ✅');
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error);
}
```

Try this directly on the main file and check the console

Comment: i added this code
` 
async function connectToMongoDB() {
  try {
...your code
  }
}

connectToMongoDB();
`

**this is what the console said:**
[1] MongoServerError: bad auth : authentication failed 
[1]     at MessageStream.<anonymous>
[1]   ok: 0,
[1]   code: 8000,
[1]   codeName: 'AtlasError',
[1]   connectionGeneration: 0,
[1]   [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(2) { 'HandshakeError', 'ResetPool' }

...so it must be a mongoDB authenication problem then i guess.. :/

Comment: it worked. it was aauthentication problem.
i created a new project on mongo db and now it worked.
Thank you very much for the help